# reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android, performance, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am creating a reCaptcha for app 
The application runs perfectly without any error but when I click on POST Button for the ReCaptcha Verification then it gives following warning:

`W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection`

finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection

I want to show alert dialog for verifying image but it not show please solve my quarries.

Comment: I have this problem too. Have you find answer?

Comment: It is about which rules you determined. Please try to change firebase rules.